MQTT WebSocket Error: "WebSocket is not available" on Port 9001
I am setting up an MQTT communication system using Mosquitto and MQTTX and I downloaded it form the official website of the mosquitto and the version is 2.0.20. I am trying to enable WebSocket communication on port 9001. However, when I attempt to connect, I encounter the following error:
ERROR: WebSocket is not available

Here’s my current Mosquitto configuration for WebSockets:
listener 9001
protocol websockets

I’ve already verified that Mosquitto is installed correctly, and the default MQTT port (1883) works fine. And I downloaded it in windows. can some one help me with this issue.
I just want to solve this problem as early as possible for my project. and i'm expecting detail solution of the issue.

Are you sure you have restarted mosquitto since making the config change (especially if running as a service)? Is the websocket listener listed in the startup logs?
